# How do I get the wallet balance from Bisq programmatically?

Tags: bisq

I have Bisq installed on Windows. Now I'm trying to fetch the current balance from PHP CLI.

I already tried to copy the `bisq_BTC.wallet` to a "Bisq" dir in the Bitcoin Core datadir (renamed to `wallet.dat`) and make it open that, but it's apparently a completely different format.

I've read the manual and find not one word about any API or command-line parameters such as: `bisq.exe --grab-btc-wallet-balance`.

How do I grab the balance without looking with my eyes in the GUI?